# RefreshError when trying to connect with gspread

Tags: gspread

I had gspread working fine for a week and suddenly trying to open spreadsheets I get the following error:

```
RefreshError: ('invalid_client: Unauthorized', {'error': 'invalid_client', 'error_description': 'Unauthorized'})
```

This was under simple use like below:

```
gc = gspread.oauth(credentials_filename='credentials.json')
master="filename"
master_file_sh = gc.open(master)
```

The authentication works fine using google's methodology and even trying reset credentials multiple time with no luck.

Any idea why it may fail? I know the message states clearly the reason but it can't be the case.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this using the credentials differently instead of realying to gspread backend like below:

```
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

import os

creds = None

if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', scope)

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', scope)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

gc=gspread.authorize(creds)
```